# Authenticate users using LDAP for SSO

Tags: ssl, ldap, single-sign-on, openldap

So i'm tasked with implementing SSO for our Windows application. Currently, after a user logs into the machine, he or she has to re-log in to our app when he or she loads the application. The application validates the user by querying a LDAP server.

What we're looking to have is for the user to automatically be logged into the app when they click on it. My understanding is that the LDAP authentication must still happen, but Im not exactly sure what the workflow would be, and how exactly we can validate a user without requiring them to re-enter a username / password. Note that this is not a web application so I can't use tools like SAML or OAuth (unless i'm mistaken about this too..?)

So my specific question is as follows:

Is it possible to use LDAP for SSO, and if so, how? Is it possible for me to authenticate a user with just his or her username, or is a password also required?

Any guidance would be appreciated, and am happy to provide further clarification if needed.

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I added a more specific question statement.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, LDAP is a protocol, which you use to communicate with databases that implement this protocol.

So LDAP databases (commonly called directories) are ... databases and so do not provide SSO functionality.

To deploy a SSO solution, you need a SSO service. All your applications will have to be "compliant" with this service in a way or another.

The only way I can think of to make a "Windows SSO" without adding a third party application is that the applications can retrieve NTLM informations in requests made by the client and uses the user data to identify him. (but in term of security, I let you judge what you think about it ;) ) . [See this php example](https://loune.net/2007/10/simple-lightweight-ntlm-in-php/)

Answer (score 0):

Some LDAP implementations, including OpenLDAP, provide some level of support the [Generic Security Service Application Program Interface (GSSAPI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Security_Services_Application_Program_Interface) or [SPNEGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPNEGO) (a specific GSSAPI implementation)

Although not trivial, it is possible to perform SSO from a "browser" that supports GSSAPI. AFIK, IE, [Firefox](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Deployment_Guide/sso-config-firefox.html), Safari and [Chrome](https://specopssoft.com/configuring-chrome-and-firefox-for-windows-integrated-authentication/) all provide some level of support for GSSAPI although each browser requires specific configuration (typically whitelisting of Servers).

There are many SSO Products that implement these features in a "probably" more secure and easier process than doing it yourself.

There are many known vulnerabilities details that have been exploited with GSAPPI/SPNEGO typically due to implementation issues.